# why exec() assigns not working? and the different with the x=?

Tags: python, namespaces, exec, python-internals

in python3.3:

```
x = 1
print('global x =', x)
def f():
    exec('x=2')
    #x = 2
    print('local in f() x =', x)
    def g():
        print('local in g() x =', x)
    g()

f()
```

in python3.3 why the resuls like this:

```
    global x = 1
    local in f() x = 1
    local in g() x = 1
```

anyone can tell me why exec('x=2') in not equal x=2

what's the difference between 'x=2' and exec('x=2')?

3x

Answer (score 1):

Locals in functions are *highly* optimized and determined at compile time, stored in an array on the frame. Each local name is merely an index in the byte code, indexing into that array.

`exec()` on the other hand tries to treat locals as a writable dictionary, but inside a function the dictionary returned by `locals()` is *not* connected to the actual locals array of a function. You cannot set locals with `exec()`.

Quoting the [`locals()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) documentation:

> **Note**: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

and from the [`exec()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> **Note**: The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

When you add the line `x = 2` inside the function, then `x` is determined to be a local by the compiler.

Comment: Python is interpreted language, when the 'compile time' happen? and How can I debug the array('Locals in functions are highly optimized and determined at compile time, stored in an array on the frame. ) whitch store the locals or look the detail of the array? 3x

Comment: @hugc: Python compiles your code to bytecode, then interprets the bytecode. You can look at the bytecode generated for a callable by using the `dis.dis()` function; `import dis; dis.dis(f)` would show you the bytecode generated for `f`. You cannot inspect the locals array (that's a C-level value)); all you are given is the frame's `f_locals` attribute, which is a dictionary *reflecting* the array into a mapping.

Comment: @hugc: see the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) for what kind of introspection you can do in Python.